# Curve the vertex of a rotating triangle in SVG

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, trigonometry, bezier

I have a function which generates a SVG "needle", which is part of a gauge (think speedometer).

```
function calculateNeedlePath(params: {
  percentage: number;
  needleLength: number;
  needleRadius: number;
}) {
  const { percentage, needleLength, needleRadius } = params;
  const thetaRad = percentageToRadians(percentage / arcSegmentSize);
  const centerX = 0;
  const centerY = 0;

  const topX = centerX - needleLength * Math.cos(thetaRad);
  const topY = centerY - needleLength * Math.sin(thetaRad);

  const leftX = centerX - needleRadius * Math.cos(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
  const leftY = centerY - needleRadius * Math.sin(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);

  const rightX = centerX - needleRadius * Math.cos(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
  const rightY = centerY - needleRadius * Math.sin(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);

  return `M ${leftX} ${leftY} C ${p1.x} ${p1.y} ${topX} ${topY} T ${rightX} ${rightY}`;
}
```

I have adapted this from Jake Trents very helpful tutorial here: https://jaketrent.com/post/rotate-gauge-needle-in-d3

I need to utilise a quadratic curve to curve the tip of the needle (the vertex of the triangle).

I have tried to position the point so that it will always be to one side of the triangle (whilst always remaining parallel to the base of the triangle) by adding these lines and adjusting the return statement as so:

```
  const angleOfHalfNeedlePoint = Math.atan(needleLength / needleRadius);
  const angleOfLineVector =
    (degreesToRadians(180) - angleOfHalfNeedlePoint * 2) / 2;

  const lengthOfBezierCurve = 10;

  const q = {
    x: centerX - lengthOfBezierCurve * Math.cos(angleOfLineVector),
    y: centerY - lengthOfBezierCurve * Math.sin(angleOfLineVector)
  };

  return `M ${leftX} ${leftY} Q ${q.x} ${q.y} ${topX} ${topY} T ${rightX} ${rightY}`;
```

The result is the needle mutates as it rotates in the gauge, and I need it to maintain a consistent shape.

A diagram:
[image]

Here is the result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please tell me if I'm wrong: you are calculating the shape of the needle in base of the angle.

Comment: @enxaneta yes, in the calculateNeedlePath function, I am calculating both the shape of the needle, and it's position within the SVG. The return string is passed into a path element.

With "code block 2", I am attempting to plot a point that will result in the tip being evenly curved, regardless of how the needle is rotated.

Honestly, I am not very knowledgeable about SVG's, I could not be using the correct strategy to achieve this also...

Comment: I'd have drawn a fixed needle and rotated it with a rotate transform.

Comment: Take the advice of Robert Longson (above). Also you may want to read about [Math.atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) for any future issues

Comment: Ok, thanks folks. I figured there should be a mathematical way to do this, as it's only four points, but I will take Mr Longson's hint. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this kinds of problems in SVG is by not calculating all vertices of your complex path, but only the easiest set of vertices(for example the vertices for a rotation of zero degrees)

This path you wrap in a group with a transform

```
<g transform="rotate(<the angle>, <origin_x_of_needle>, <origin_y_of_needle>">

  <path d="... <very complex> path" />

</g>
```

Though this is not exactly the answer you asked for, I hope this will help